# What is causing this random GUID in generated sql query (OData + EF)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odata

I have a REST API setup with OData v4 and Entity Framework (v6.4).  Whenever I perform an expand in the api (`v1/api/main?$expand=Items`) the sql generated contains this random GUID in it.  I'm pretty sure this is being used to "identify" the expanded items but is there a way to either get rid of it or change it to be a parameter?

This is causing major issues with sql logging as well as query plan optimization.

The generated sql is below (I've omitted selects as well as changed field / table names)

```
SELECT
    [Project3].[ID] AS [ID],
    [Project3].[C1] AS [C1],
    [Project3].[ID2] AS [ID2],
   ...
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Limit1].[ID] AS [ID],
        [Limit1].[ID2] AS [ID2],
        ...
        CASE WHEN ([Limit2].[ID3] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C5]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (21) [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], [Project1].[ID2] AS [ID2], ...
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
                [Extent1].[ID2] AS [ID2],
                ...
                N'538522f0-f041-4fc3-9ce9-5b9e7ba62d4b' AS [C1],
                N'Items' AS [C2],
                20 AS [C3]
                FROM [DBSchema].[vMain] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[OtherID] = @p__linq__1)
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (@p__linq__2) [Project2].[ID3] AS [ID3], [Project2].[ID] AS [ID], [Project2].[ID2] AS [ID2], ...
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent2].[ID3] AS [ID3],
                [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID],
                [Extent2].[ID2] AS [ID2],
               ...
                N'538522f0-f041-4fc3-9ce9-5b9e7ba62d4b' AS [C1]
                FROM [DBSchema].[vItems] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE ([Limit1].[ID] = [Extent2].[ID]) AND ([Limit1].[ID2] = [Extent2].[ID2])
            )  AS [Project2]
            ORDER BY [Project2].[ID3] ASC ) AS [Limit2]
    )  AS [Project3]
    ORDER BY [Project3].[ID] ASC, [Project3].[ID2] ASC, [Project3].[C5] ASC
```

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: Sorry, EF version is 6.4, I'll update the original post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  It's a ModelID.  Recently in Microsoft.AspNet.OData version 7.2 they fixed an issue where it wasn't respecting the EnableConstantParameterization flag.

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/f372ead362c40c24c1f29ff4f27a7b7659302273/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Query/Expressions/SelectExpandBinder.cs#L282